# Questions on continuously differentiable function on $[a,b]$

Tags: derivatives, continuity

Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function. Normally we define derivatives of $f$ only at interior points in $[a,b]$. But when we write $f\in C^1([a,b])$, it means that $f$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$ and the derivatives are continuous on $[a,b]$. Therefore, I'm confusing since this defines its derivatives even at $x=a,b$. Whenever we write $f\in C^1([a,b])$, should I interpret this as $f$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$, $f$ is one-side differentiable at $x=a,b$ and $f'$ is continuous on $[a,b]$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is the definition.

Alternatively, you could imagine $f=F|_{[a,b]}$ is the restriction to $[a,b]$ of a function $F$ that has continuous derivatives on $(a-\epsilon,b+\epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Where could I find the definition I described in the above? Could you let me know any source?

Comment: @user156043 Well, you can prove it yourself. If the lateral derivative exit, then you can always extend the function following the tangent at that point. Conversely, if you have the extension the restriction has continuous lateral derivatives.